# Group by and return all index values where a substring of text exists in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-analysis

I have a df with the following structure

```
   vid  sid   pid      url 
1   A    A1   page     ABCDEF   
2   A    A1   page     DEF123
3   A    A1   page     GHI345
4   A    A1   page     JKL345
5   B    B1   page     AB12345EF
6   B    B2   page     IJK
7   B    B2   page     XYZ
8   C    C1   page     ABCEF

dict = {'vid':{1:'A',2:'A',3:'A',4:'A',5:'B',6:'B',7:'B',8:'C'},
        'sid':{1:'A1',2:'A1',3:'A1',4:'A1',5:'B1',6:'B2',7:'B2',8:'C1'},
        'page':{1:'page',2:'page',3:'page',4:'page',5:'page',6:'page',7:'page',8:'pge'},
        'url':{1:'ABC',2:'DEF',3:'GHI',4:'JKL',5:'ABC',6:'IJK',7:'XYZ',8:'ABC'}
}
```

I also have a list substrings

`lst = ['AB','EF']`

Essentially, I want to group by `sid` and check every single row in `url`. If all the elements in the list exist as a substring in at least one row, then return the `sid`.If not, filter out the `sid` from the df. The substrings inside `url` aren't sequential.

Psuedo-code

```
group by sid
if row in url contains all the substrings in lst
       pass
if no row in url contains all substrings in lst
       remove the `sid` from the df
```

Result from applying the logic above to the df using `lst`

```
enter code here

      vid  sid   pid      url 
1   A    A1   page     ABCDEF   
2   A    A1   page     DEF123
3   A    A1   page     GHI345
4   A    A1   page     JKL345
5   B    B1   page     AB12345EF
8   C    C1   page     ABCEF
```

Comment: `df[df.url.apply(lambda s: any([x in s for x in lst])).groupby(df.sid).transform(any)]`

Comment: note that the dictionary you shared is different from the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the boolean mask for url in `lst` :

```py
# `all` check for rows that have both `AB` and `EF`
mask = [all(a in ent for a in lst)  for ent in df.url]
mask = pd.Series(mask, index = df.index)

# Group mask with `Sid` and filter `df`:

df.loc[mask.groupby(df.sid).transform('any')]

  vid sid   pid        url
1   A  A1  page     ABCDEF
2   A  A1  page     DEF123
3   A  A1  page     GHI345
4   A  A1  page     JKL345
5   B  B1  page  AB12345EF
8   C  C1  page      ABCEF
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this but I think its returning sids where one element of the list exists in the `url` column. I was looking for only sids where all the elements of the list exist in a minimum of 1 row.

Comment: nice observation @Sebazz44; updated the code. see if it covers your use case, or still has a leak in the logic

Comment: i actually solved it by switching the regex pipe operator to the `AND` equivalent, but your solution got me close enough :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean indexing:

```
import pandas as pd
gb_df = df.groupby('sid')['url'].transform(lambda x : [x.tolist()]*len(x))
indexing = gb_df.apply(lambda li: any(any(el in text for text in li) for el in lst))

output = df[indexing]
```

Output:

```
      vid  sid   pid      url 
1   A    A1   page     ABCDEF   
2   A    A1   page     DEF123
3   A    A1   page     GHI345
4   A    A1   page     JKL345
5   B    B1   page     AB12345EF
8   C    C1   page     ABCEF
```